# Cross Plattform build target for OS X and iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, xcode6

Is it possible to generate OS X and iOS binaries from one same swift source code file in Xcode 6?
And if yes, how?

Comment: I doubt it as OSX have different API calls to iOS i.e. UITableView (iOS) and NSTableView (OSX).

Comment: swift-lang.org and Apples Swift aren't related to each other.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Same as current. You build different targets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The way you share Swift code between multiple targets in a project is no different from how you share ObjC code.

For an example, see the new [Lister app sample code in the developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Lister-Swift/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014512). That project builds an OS X app and an iOS app, and for each platform it builds the app, a Notification Center Today View extension, and a bundled framework supporting both.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely. See WWDC 2014 Session 233 (Friday 9 am) or check out the [documentation on Xcode targets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html). (h/t uchuugaka)